# How is this below code identifying prime numbers

Tags: java, primes

This is the code that identifies the prime numbers up to the given number. If you input, say 7, the returned ArrayList would have all the first 7 prime numbers in it.

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> calcPrime(int inp) 
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(3);

        int counter = 4;

        while(arr.size() < inp) 
        {
            // 23 and 25
            if(counter % 2 != 0 && counter%3 != 0) 
            {
                int temp = 4;
                while(temp*temp <= counter) 
                {
                    if(counter % temp == 0)
                        break;
                    temp ++;
                }
                if(temp*temp > counter) 
                {
                    arr.add(counter);
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

My question is this. I understand that this code is filtering all the numbers which are divisible by 2 and 3. But for all other numbers, say 23 or 25, it is just relying on the squares of numbers from 4.

I want to know how this is achieving its goal. Please help me understanding this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division

Comment: Add some prints to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The bit that's doing the checking is this:

```
                if(counter % temp == 0)
                    break;
```

It's not actually relying on the squares of numbers at all. That's just telling it when to stop checking the numbers.

First it does some initial set up. It knows that 2 and 3 are primes, so it adds them to its list.

Then, starting at 4, it checks to see if the number is a prime. If it is, it adds it to the array, if it's not it skips out and checks the next number.

So "Checks to see if the number is prime" is done by:
first checking if it's divisible by 2 or divisible by 3:

```
    if(counter % 2 != 0 && counter%3 != 0)
```

Then, starting at 4 again, doing the same check: Is my potential prime (`counter`) divisible by this number (`temp`) ?

```
        if(counter % temp == 0)
```

If that's the case, it's not a prime number so it does the `break` command and checks the next `counter` to see if that's a prime.

If `counter` is not divisible by `temp` it increments `temp` and checks again.  When `temp` is so large it's not worth checking if it's a factor any more, the algorithm knows that `counter` is a prime, and adds it to the list.

The `temp*temp` bit is because when it's checking to see if a number is a prime, it doesn't have to check all of the numbers up to `counter`.  if `temp*temp` is greater than our target, then for `temp` to be a factor, the other factor has to be less than `temp`, and it has already been checked.

Answer (score 0):

`%` means remainder when divided by, and is the snippet doing the actual work.  If the remainder is zero, then it divides exactly so the number is not prime.

The square part is because you can optimize a bit by only considering the numbers less than the square root (because if a number larger then the square root divide, then the result is *less* than the square root and should have been caught earlier)